# GMAP control doesn't appear

Tags: c#, wpf, google-maps, mvvm, gmap.net

I will need to use the GMAP.Presentation in my app. I already installed using NuGet and reboot the app, but for some reason the control doesn't appear. I've already checked the references and it's all good. Image to prove :)

[image]

Someone has any tips?

Best regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try right clicking in the toolbox, select "Choose Items", click "Browse", navigate to the DLL, and select the DLL.  The controls should now appear in the toolbox panel.